# Is there a plugin directory software like Firefox Addon or Wordpress Plugin Directory

Tags: looking-for-a-script, open-source, plugin

Nowadays browsers and content management systems all have the plugin/module/addon/theme systems for users to extend at their own will. Developers can also submit plugin to share the plugin with others. The most famous examples are Firefox Addon and Wordpress Plugin Directory.

I want to ask that if there is an open source web system specifically designed for this need - to host plugins? Not just one plugin, but all plugins for one software?

Ideally it should allow developers to upload the plugin, have a public version for each update, and client software can check if there are any plugin available through the directory's API.

As an example, a CMS can have one such directory to host/display theme files.

Also is there a better keyword to describe this kind of system?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to see an example (drupal based) go to http://www.scriptspot.com/

It is a 3dsmax scipting plugins platform that by what I understood - is doing exactly what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

How about using Github to host the code for the plugin.? handles versioning and others can subscribe to changes. includes a q&a section. I find myself using it more and more to keep up to date on plugins for Wordpress.
Or are you talking about something you can host yourself privately?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I want is a layer deeper than Github, acting as a directory for the user to find/update plugins and for developers to submit/maintain plugins. This will be used for another open source blogging program to host all of its themes/plugins. Ideally it should have an API for individual installation to update plugins from it.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply install a CMS like joomla with an appropriate module to fulfill your need (download of plugins, accesses, discussions).

If you want to manage versioning and client dynamic updates, the answer is a distributed revision control system like git (eg.: github.com)

AFAIK, there is no known web system already packaged for this, you have to build yours

Comment: saying to install joomla and a module is not at all what the is being asked for.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Do you know what module of joomla would fit the task for this?

Comment: @lulalala I meant, combining different modules. Example, a download management module like http://www.jdownloads.com/ (they have a demo site)